# Android: Unable to load a system library

Tags: java, android, loadlibrary, hdmi

I am working on a proprietary app for Android boxes which reads HDMI input and displays it within a part of the screen. For this we are using R9 Mini Android TV box ([link](http://eweat.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008848465509/pdtl/HD-set-top/1143517456/TV-Box-R9-Mini.htm)). The vendor provided with the source code of a sample application to read HDMI input, but the app fails to launch throwing error pop-up (Unfortunately, SourceIn has stopped).

Following is the exception stack trace:

```
02-28 15:38:36.988 3232-3232/rtk.com.RealtekSourceIn W/art: Method processed more than once: void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(android.app.Activity)
02-28 15:38:37.090 3232-3232/rtk.com.RealtekSourceIn A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
02-28 15:38:37.090 3232-3232/rtk.com.RealtekSourceIn A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
02-28 15:38:37.090 3232-3232/rtk.com.RealtekSourceIn A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
02-28 15:38:37.090 3232-3232/rtk.com.RealtekSourceIn A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3232 (RealtekSourceIn)
```

The crash is initiated from the code within a library dependency. On debugging the decompiled .class file. Following is the code where the above error is thrown:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("realtek_runtime");
}
```

I have seen the .so files at /system/lib/ folder and found `librealtek_runtime.so` to be present, so I am unable to understand why loadLibrary is failing.

Following is the relevant code:

RTKSourceInActivity:

```
public class RTKSourceInActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG="HDMIRxActivity";
    private ViewGroup m_Root;
    private HDMIRxPlayer m_HDMIRxPlayer = null;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private byte[] mCapture;
    private static final long SCREENSHOT_SLOT = 200;
    private boolean mIsFullScreen = true;

    private File mRecordFile;
    private boolean mRecordOn = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
        super.onResume();
        if(hasRtkMusicPlaybackService()) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
            i.putExtra("command", "stop");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
        m_Root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
        m_HDMIRxPlayer = new HDMIRxPlayer(this, m_Root, 1920, 1080);
    }

...
}
```

HDMIRxPlayer:

```
public HDMIRxPlayer(Context context, ViewGroup parent, int width, int height)
{
    mContext = context;
    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(HDMIRXCallback);
    mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height);
    parent.addView(mSurfaceView);

    mHDMIRX = new RtkHDMIRxManager(); // Exception here 

    IntentFilter hdmiRxFilter = new IntentFilter(HDMIRxStatus.ACTION_HDMIRX_PLUGGED);
    mContext.registerReceiver(hdmiRxHotPlugReceiver, hdmiRxFilter);
}
```

`RtkHDMIRxManager` is a .class within the dependency jar (realtek-classes) given by the vendor.

When I have placed debug points within decompiled version of `RtkHDMIRxManager`, I found the exception at:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("realtek_runtime");
}
```

Any direction pointing towards the solution would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to resolve:

1. I had to use `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` and sign app with corresponding `pem` and `pk8` files.
2. Install the app, use adb commands to move app into /system/ directory. Not it is a system app. You can share all system resources now.